# WP Listbox: Scroll per list item instead of per group item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox and would like to use logical scrolling (CanContentScroll=True).
I have one to a few groups in my ListBox and each group can contain a lot of items, stacked vertically.

When I scroll, the scrolling happens per group item, instead of per list item. In some cases I only have one big group, and then I can't scroll, even when not all items are visible.

I know I could split up the listbox in one listbox per possible group, but I was wondering if there is a way to configure the listbox to scroll per listitem, instead of per groupitem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a ListView instead of a ListBox fixed the issue.